# Projections of functions of random variables

Tags: random-variables, lp-spaces, random-walk, entropy

Say we have a random variable $X$, and a function $g(X)$.

I'm looking at expressions of the form $$ g^{-1}\left( E( g(X) )\right)$$ where $E$ is the expectation operator.

It's a generalization of the $p$-norm, but is there a more-or-less standard name for that sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains very little information (about what $g$ is,... ),​so it quite hard for us to give you a satisfying answer.

You might be interested in Orlicz spaces, and thus Orlicz norms. They can be applied to random variables ([see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlicz_space)) and they generalize the $L^p$ norm.